# Last value of series vs entire series in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to understand [this Pine-Script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/U1SJ8ubc-HalfTrend/).

I am particularly baffled by these two declarations:

```
var float maxLowPrice = nz(low[1], low)
var float minHighPrice = nz(high[1], high)
```

I understand that var declaration means you declare the variable only once, as opposed to a series.

**nz** is supposed to set to the first argument if it is not na, otherwise it sets it to the second argument.

Hence, if low[1](https://www.tradingview.com/script/U1SJ8ubc-HalfTrend/)(current value of low) is not na maxLowPrice will be set to this value, makes sense so far.

However, if it is na it is set to the whole series low. What is the point of that? Why set the variable that is declared only once to a series. All I know is if I don't have this contingency the script does not run properly, namely the minHighPrice is set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
low[1] is actually previous candle low and low is current candle low. low[1] will not be available at the first candle and low will be used only. You can replace the nz(low[1],low) to low directly.

Comment: I understand that. My question is why do the first declaration with nz(low[1], low), why not just do var float maxLowPrice = low[1] ?